# How to install audacity software in Ubuntu?

Tags: audacity

I am new to Ubuntu and trying to install audacity on Ubuntu. I tried these commands & didn't work.

`sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:audacity-team/daily && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install audacity && sudo apt-get -f install`

can anybody please help me in this. Thanks in Advance

Comment: You shouldn't run `sudo apt-get -f install` unless you get messages about missing dependencies or broken installations.  This command is not part of a normal installation procedure.

Comment: audacity is in universe repository. You don't need to add a PPA for that. And add PPA only you are aware of the risk

Answer (score 38):

Is there a reason you are not using the Ubuntu main repo? If not:

```
sudo apt-get install audacity
```

Comment: sudo apt-get install audacity worked well.

Comment: I can't believe this isn't written down on the audacity page. It's so simple and functional.